# Monte Carlo Code does wait till calculated

Tags: vba, excel, refresh, montecarlo

I want to run the following monte carlo simulation:

```
  Sub MonteCarlo()
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  Dim x As Integer

        For x = 1 To 25

            Application.Calculate
            Do
            DoEvents
            Loop While Not Application.CalculationState = xlDone

        Worksheets("Monte Carlo").Range("A" & x).Value = Worksheets("Ex-Ante Te").Range("B2").Value
        Worksheets("Monte Carlo").Range("B" & x).Value = Worksheets("Ex-Ante Te").Range("B3").Value
        Worksheets("Monte Carlo").Range("C" & x).Value = Worksheets("Ex-Ante Te").Range("B4").Value

        Next
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

The Values in B2, B3, and B4 are dependent on random numbers, which are supposed to recalculate themselves after every loop. However, the code does not break and wait until the new random numbers are created and the sheet has recalculated, as this part does not seem to work:

```
 Application.Calculate
           Do
       DoEvents
     Loop While Not Application.CalculationState = xlDone
```

I also tried this one, which doesn't work either:

```
Application.Calculate
If Not Application.CalculationState = xlDone Then
DoEvents
End If
```

For instance: If I run the monte carlo I get values, which cannot be (values for B2 and B3 that are impossible to fit together). Moreover, when I run the monte carlo manually (recalc, write the numbers down) the sheet works fine. So it must have something to do with the fact, that the code does not seem to wait.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried specifically checking whether you're getting new random values? Like maybe doing `Debug.Print Worksheets("Monte Carlo").Range("A" & x).Value` before and after `Application.Calculate`? For me, random value formulas on the sheet definitely get recalculated on a manual `Application.Calculate` - no waiting for events was necessary.

Comment: Hi, yes they do get recalculated. The problem is that the code does not seem to wait until all random variables are recalculated and all formulas are updated.

Comment: Hey, I just used the Debug.Print method and the numbers I get in the immediate window are actually fine. However, the numbers I copy via Worksheets("Monte Carlo").Range("A" & x).Value = Worksheets("Ex-Ante Te").Range("B2").Value are not fine. 

Does anybody know why these are different?